# ASTStoreKit non-consumable iap where to close

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, storekit

I am using ASTStoreKit for IAP non-consumable purchases. Does anyone has any example how to do this ? I have two non-consumables which is in the app ( which I only unlock if purchase was successful ) and two for which I have to download a content from own server. In ASTStoreController.m ( this is from `https://github.com/anystone/AnystoneStoreKit/blob/master/README.mdown` )

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) 
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) 
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased: 
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed: 
                [self failedTransaction:transaction]; 
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored: 
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Is right way to download and then complete transaction ( couple MB ) ?
I download content async way and then unzip and then to call complete ?

Comment: Do you want to check in from any of the above methods which Inapp purchase is successful?

Comment: @Manthan I get SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased flag before I have downloaded content and I want to avoid if they lost connection or anything to lose content.